# How do I insert the the tetrahedron set into the CGAL's data structure?

Tags: c++, mesh, cgal

I have a set of tetrahedral mesh, and that connectivity (a tetrahedron has four triangles, and a triangle has three vertices) in my simple data structure.

I wish to insert the tetrahedral data into the CGAL's data sturcutre. How do I achieve that?

Moreover, I want to find surface's triangle using CGAL.

Comment: You can use the [Triangulation_3](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_3/classCGAL_1_1Triangulation__3.html) .

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Are there any sample code?

Comment: Yes, in the Example section, at the bottom of the left menu in the link I gave you.